# One button for 2 different actions

Tags: java, android

I have "send" Button inside dialogFragment that onClick event push new data to firebase under key value.

I want this button to be also like an "update" button when the user click on particular button. the data will update in firebase under the same key value as before.

This is the send button onClick method:

```
send_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    //some code .....//

                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                    str_key = newPost.getKey();
                    trempData = new TrempData(str_key, str_uid, str_name, str_phone, str_from, str_to, str_date, str_time, str_extra, str_timestamp);
                    newPost.setValue(trempData);
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Tremp Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dismiss();
                }


        });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: When he open the dialog what the start state

Comment: I'm not sure I undrestand your question.. 
The start state is when the user click the send btn new data pushed to firebase

Comment: After it pushed what you want the state of the button upgrade

Comment: I want to change the state after i clicked on particular btn. 
I will edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: ok i get you i will answer that

Answer (score 1):

More important than the implementation is the way you think it can be done. So, the basic approach in these cases is to use a **boolean** variable.

Why? Because it can be used to indicate if the button is in a particular state or not. 
So, you can do something like this.

```
boolean b=false;
//set your button in the initial state you want(submit in your case)
 //In onClick() method
if(!b){         //button in submit state
b=true;        
//do submit stuff
send_btn.setText("update");
}
else{         //button in update state
b=false;
//do update stuff
send_btn.setText("submit");
}
```

In this case, true value of b indicates that the button is in "update" state.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Example :

```
private final int BUTTON_UPDATE = 1;
private final int BUTTON_SEND = 2;
private int buttonStatus = 0;

send_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          switch(buttonStatus)
          {
            case BUTTON_UPDATE: { // your update code here}
            case BUTTON_SEND : { // your send code here
        }
```

the `buttonStatus` will control what operation the button will do.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put a boolean in sharedPrefrences and keep to false initially when
       user sends data to firebase update boolean to true.
2. in onClick check if the value is true or false using if else and
   execute code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tag of the view for this and update the state as your need

```
  Button button = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (button.getTag().equals("send")) {
                    // push the value to firebase

                    // set the tag to update and the text
                    button.setTag("update");
                    button.setText("update");
                }else if (button.getTag().equals("update")){
                    // update the value in firebase
                }
            }
        });
```

xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="send"
        android:text="send" />
```

Comment: i want it to be changed to "update" only when i click on specific button wich located in listview (in another activity). but when i try to change the tag the app shut down

Comment: this code in the answer if there are in the same activity if in another activity i think you should use prefrence to store the value